# Oracle dbms_scheduler.create_job Error

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-06550, dbms-scheduler, pls-00103

I am trying to create a simple scheduled event in an oracle 10g database. I have been trying to use dbms_scheduler.create_job. Here is the script I wrote:

> begin dbms_scheduler.create_job (
>
> job_name => 'disengagementChecker',
>
> job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
>
> job_action => 'INSERT INTO
>   PatientClassRelObs(patientClassID,observationTypeID) VALUES (1, 11)',
>
> start_date => SYSDATE,
>
> repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=1',
>
> comments => 'Iam tesing scheduler'); end;

When I run this, oracle throws these errors

> ORA-06550: line 15, column 3:
>
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ;   The symbol
>   ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.

I don't understand whats causes this error. Do you know what causes this error? Or why this is happening?

Thank you in advance!

-David

Comment: Please post the actual code you're using. What you have posted does not consist of 15 lines!

Answer (score 0):

`JOB_ACTION` must be a valid PL/SQL block, not just a valid SQL statement.  Use this:

```
job_action => '
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PatientClassRelObs(patientClassID,observationTypeID)
    VALUES (1, 11);
  END;',
```

---

**UPDATE**

Maybe this is a problem with a specific environment or some code not posted.  To troubleshoot, start with something that's known to work, and add one small change at a time until something breaks.

Start with this code, using SQL*Plus.

```
SQL> begin
  2     dbms_scheduler.create_job(
  3             job_name   => 'TEST_JOB',
  4             job_type   => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  5             job_action => 'BEGIN NULL; END;',
  6             start_date => systimestamp,
  7             enabled    => true);
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select status, log_date from dba_scheduler_job_run_details where job_name = 'TEST_JOB';

STATUS                         LOG_DATE
------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUCCEEDED                      26-MAR-14 11.37.59.533000 PM -05:00
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but I am still getting the same errors as before. By any chance, do I need to any import or set-up before I can use dbms_scheduler.create_job? (Im new to oracle)